# Show that $ f $ is invertible with $ f^{-1} $.

Tags: functions

$$
f:\mathbb R^{+}\to [-5,\infty)
$$
$$
f(x)=9x^{2}+6x-5
$$
$$
f^{-1}(y)=({\frac{(\sqrt{y+6})-1}{3}})
$$

Now I have to show that $ f $ is invertible with $f^{-1}$

I'm trying to show that $f^{-1}\circ f(x)=x$ and $f\circ f^{-1}=y$

**I have done to some extend:**
$$
f^{-1}\circ f(x)=f^{-1}(f(x))
$$
$$
= f^{-1}(9x^{2}+6x-5)
$$
$$
={\frac{\sqrt{(9x^{2}+6x-5)+6}-1}{3}}
$$
$$
={\frac{\sqrt{9x^{2}+6x+1}-1}{3}}
$$

Now from here it is clear that it it won't be equal to $ x $.

Kindly tell me where I'm getting wrong , is my process wrong or there is any calculation mistake.

Comment: You haven't gone wrong at all, and what's more, you last line does in fact equal $x$. Try factorising $9x^2+6x+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who says that won't be equal to x? $9x^2+6x+1=(3x+1)^2$. Plugging that in, we see that the last line is equal to x!

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly equal to $x$, because $9x^2+6x+1=(3x+1)^2$